# How to generate list with repeating items?

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension, repeat, flatten

Suppose I want to create a list like the following with a list comprehension:

```py
["2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4"]
```

I have tried:

```py
>>> [*[str(n)] * 3 for n in range(2, 5)]

  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: iterable unpacking cannot be used in comprehension
```

and

```py
>>> [str(n) * 3 for n in range(2, 5)]
['222', '333', '444']
```

where I got the numbers, but together in one string, and

```py
>>> [[str(n)] * 3 for n in range(2, 5)]
[['2', '2', '2'], ['3', '3', '3'], ['4', '4', '4']]
```

where I got a nested list, but want a flat one. Can this be done in a simple way, or do I have to take the nested list method and flatten the list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way you could do this with list comprehension is by using integer division.

```
[str(n // 3) for n in range(6, 15)]
```

Comment: Wow, cool, I would never have thought of this ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3):

A nested for loop is your best bet. I think this is the simplest solution:

```
[str(n) for n in range(2, 5) for i in range(3)]
```

Comment: OMG, whyever didn't I think of THAT ? Thanks too ! (I'll have a hard time choosing one to accept …)

Comment: While the accepted answer by @duckboycool is perfectly good and works, I find this answer more intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function [chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) function
from the itertools library in order to flatten the list.

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain(*[[str(n)] * 3 for n in range(2, 5)]))
['2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3', '4', '4', '4']
```